# Getting all records from sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating a database and I need to read all records from the database, but my program keeps crashing at this statement:

```
newWord= db.getAllRecords();
```

I assume there is an issue with getAllRecords(), as Eclipse indicates no errors.

```
 public Cursor getAllRecords() {
 db = dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();//obtains the writable database
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,KEY_WORD}, null, null, null,      null, null);//the query used to obtain all records form the table

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: define crash?  Post the stack trace

Comment: Nope just me being a retard :/ I misspelt the column name in the create string

Answer (score 18):

Here is what I do to get all contents from a table..

```
public ArrayList<MyObject> getAllElements() {

    ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MY_TABLE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try {

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        try {

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
                    //only one column
                    obj.setId(cursor.getString(0));

                    //you could add additional columns here..

                    list.add(obj);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

        } finally {
            try { cursor.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }

    } finally {
         try { db.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void printTableData(String table_name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name, null);

    if(cur.getCount() != 0){
        cur.moveToFirst();

        do{
            String row_values = "";

            for(int i = 0 ; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++){
                row_values = row_values + " || " + cur.getString(i);
            }

            Log.d("LOG_TAG_HERE", row_values);

        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Initialize TABLE:
    private static String TABLE="your_table_name";
```

For getting list of all records, write following method into your database class:

```
public ArrayList<RecentStickerModel> getAllRecentRecords() {

    ArrayList<RecentStickerModel> listStickers = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    String q = "SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='" + TABLE + "'";
    Cursor cursorTable = db.rawQuery(q, null);

    if (cursorTable != null && cursorTable.moveToFirst()) {

        String tableName = cursorTable.getString(0);
        cursorTable.close();

        if (TABLE.equals(tableName)) {

            String query = "Select * from " + TABLE ;

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                Logger.e(TAG, "cursor size:" + cursor.getCount());

                int catNameCI = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT_NAME);
                int imagePathCI = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE_PATH);
                int lastStickerTimeCI = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LAST_STICKER_TIME);


                do {

                    RecentStickerModel model = new RecentStickerModel();
                    model.setCatName(cursor.getString(catNameCI));
                    model.setImgStickerPath(cursor.getString(imagePathCI));
                    model.setLastStickerTime(cursor.getString(lastStickerTimeCI));


                    listStickers.add(model);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        db.close();
    }

    return listStickers;
}
```

Then call the following method where you want:

```
arrayListRecent=stickersListDatabase.getAllRecentRecords();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name", null);
        if(c!=null){
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
```